# An amazing behavior on list,tuple,... objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Consider these 3 short snippets:

Snippet 1:

```
nation = ['Roman', 'Egypt', 'Greek', 'Chinese', 'Islamic', 'Mayan', 'Persian', 'Mongol']
golden_age = ['27BC-1453AD', '3150BC-30BC', '800BC-600AD', '221BC-1912AD', '750AD-1257AD', '2000BC-1540AD', '550BC-651AD', '1206AD-1368AD']
a = zip(nation, golden_age)
print(a)
```

Snippet 2:

```
b = list(a)
print('b',b)
```

Snippet 3:

```
c = tuple(a)
print('c',c)
```

---

Suppose at first I run snippet 1. Then the second and the third. Amazingly the third snippet prints `c()` (It seems that the object `a` is gone after I passed it to the list constructor in snippet 2. So when converting it to tuple the result is null!)

Now change the run order to 1 -> 3 -> 2.
This time, the second snippet prints null list! I looks like that the tuple constructor has eaten the object `a`.

WHY tuple should affect its input argument? (also for list and maybe others!)

Comment: That's because `zip` is a generator in python 3. Use the same method e.g. `list(a)` 3 times in a row and see the behaviour.